# Determine signatures of overloaded member functions

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, overloading, function-signature

Given `some_type` with a member function `f` it is possible to determine `f`'s signature like this (and say let us place it in a tuple):

```
template <typename R, typename T, typename... A>
std::tuple<R, A...> signature_of_impl(R (T::*)(A...));

template <typename T>
using signature_of_member_f = decltype(signature_of_impl(&T::f));

struct some_type
{
    int f(char, float);
};

using some_type_f_signature = signture_of_member_f<some_type>;
```

This obviously fails badly if `f` is overloaded. Is it possible to determine signatures of all existing overloads of `f` within `some_type`?

Comment: What do you mean by "Determine signatures of all existing overloads"? You want to iterate over them?

Comment: @AndyProwl I want to get some type that will contain this information, like tuple of tuples of signatures above. Then I can iterate over it if needed.

Comment: You definitely cannot do this :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can "ask" the compiler for the type of a specific function.

But there's no **[reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)** in C++, you can't query what functions or even overloads of the same function exist in a class.

Comment: Reflection implies run-time queries, I want compile-time ones. C++ allows to do things that seem impossible at first in complicated roundabout ways. I was hoping for such a possibility.

Comment: True, but still the compiler "tricks" to get information about a class are always explicit. Even SFINAE required you to be explicit so SFINAE can happen and the right type is chosen and set.